# Why udhcpd doesn't respond to DHCP requests?

Tags: dhcp, dhclient

I'm trying to configure a DHCP server with `udhcpd.conf` at the address 192.168.100.30. Here is the content of the file:

```
# Sample udhcpd configuration file (/etc/udhcpd.conf)

# The start and end of the IP lease block

start       192.168.100.25  #default: 192.168.0.20
end         192.168.100.29  #default: 192.168.0.254


# The interface that udhcpd will use

interface   eth0        #default: eth0


# The maximim number of leases (includes addressesd reserved
# by OFFER's, DECLINE's, and ARP conficts

#max_leases 254     #default: 254


#Examles
opt dns 8.8.8.8
option  subnet  255.255.255.240
opt router  192.168.100.30
option  dns 8.8.8.4     # appened to above DNS servers for a total of 3
option  domain  local
option  lease   864000      # 10 days of seconds
```

Then if on another machine I run

```
dhclient -v -d -s 192.168.100.30 eth0
```

The result is

```
/# dhclient -v -d -s 192.168.100.30 eth0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/b6:60:eb:02:f7:c1
Sending on   LPF/eth0/b6:60:eb:02:f7:c1
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 192.168.100.30 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 192.168.100.30 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 192.168.100.30 port 67 interval 13
```

Using tcpdump on the server I was able to see that it receives the requests, so the client appears to work. Anyway, the server does not reply to the request. Any idea of how I can fix it?

Comment: Why do you put `-s <ip>` as `dhclient` option? It works this way - a client does not have any IP, it sends request (discovery) to broadcast... IMO as your client does not have an IP yet it cannot work. Omit `-s <ip>`.

Comment: @JiriB it worked! Thank you. Add this as an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your client doesn't have any IPv4 yet, putting `-s <ip>` as `dhclient` option cannot work.

Comment: Reading the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient) of the command, I would have expected the `-s` to work. Anyway, removing the option (as @JiriB suggested) worked.